# What is wrong with my recursive fibonacci program?

Tags: c++, recursion, fibonacci

I am unsure what the fault in my logic is. Sample output:

```
How many terms of the Fibonacci Sequence do you wish to compute?
1
1
1
--How many terms of the Fibonacci Sequence do you wish to compute?
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
```

Why is it doing this?

```
    // Recursive Fibonacci Sequence
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double fib(double number);

int main(void) {
        double number;
        cout << "How many terms of the Fibonacci Sequence do you wish to compute?" << endl;
        cin >> number;

        for(int i = 0; i <= number; ++i)
                cout << fib(number) << endl;
} // end main

// function fib definition
double fib(double number) {
        if((number == 0) || (number == 1))
                return number;
        else
                return fib(number - 1) + fib(number - 2);
} // end function fib
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at your loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= number; ++i)
    cout << fib(number) << endl;
```

Notice how the body of the loop doesn't use `i`... it always calls `fib(number)`. Changing that to `fib(i)` will fix it.

(It's not terribly efficient, in that you'll end up recalculating values each time, but that's a separate matter. While you *could* put the printing in `fib`, that mixes the concerns of "what to do with the results" and "computing the Fibonacci sequence".)

Comment: "It's not terribly efficient" -- it's the naïve, O(2^n) solution to the Fibonacci sequence. But +1.

Comment: @larsmans: It's worse than that, because it's being called `n` times. Even if the `fib` function is changed to the simple O(n) iterative approach, it'll still be O(n^2) unnecessarily - there are ways round that, but I think it's beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Make it:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= number; ++i)
    cout << fib(i) << endl;
```

Comment: and also please note that you shouldn't use double numbers for direct comparison. In this case a fibonacci number is just an integer always...

Comment: In this case, there's no problem with the comparisons.  The numbers he compares started as exact integral values, and are decrements, so should remain exact integral values.

Comment: @Unni: it _is_ always an integer, but better able to handle numbers over 4.2billion

Answer (score 1):

You should just pass 'i' as the parameter in your for loop not 'number'